# Rails uninitialized constant User::Cooky

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a feeling this is a small "s" missing somewhere but after 48h, I just can't find my mistake:

I have 2 models: Users and Cookies. A user can have many Cookies. A cookie belongs to a Cookie.

When I try to do a simple current_user.cookies, i have this error:

```
uninitialized constant User::Cooky
```

I double and triple checked if I had a plural mistake somewhere but I just can't find anything wrong.

here is my cookie table migration

```
class CreateCookies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :cookies do |t|
      t.string :value
      t.string :value2
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :network, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

cookie.rb

```
class Cookie < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :network
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :room_users
  has_many :rooms, through: :room_users
  has_many :cookies, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The error is not in the code provided. I would take a break and then check if you have an unsaved file or something else thats easy to overlook.

Comment: `A cookie belongs to a Cookie` -> `A Cookie belongs to an User`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a pluralization error, maybe you have some custom inflections setup in `config/initializers/inflections.rb` or anywhere using `ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections`

Answer (score 0):

Dorian thanks you set me up on the right track. It was a problem with inflections:
I added to **inflections.rb**

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'cookie', 'cookies'
end
```

Now it works!!